# How to Create Offline Installer for Visual Studio Community 2017 UWP?

Tags: uwp

I'm Wondering how to save the complete installer for Visual Studio Community 2017 UWP onto a USB stick for later install.  If I download it from Microsoft, it requires that my computer is connected to the internet for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Download vs_community.exe from Microsoft and run from Powershell:

```
.\vs_community.exe --layout c:\vs2017uwb `
     --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor `
     --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal `
     --add Component.GitHub.VisualStudio  `
     --lang en-US
```

(Note: backtick is a line continuation in powershell)

The total download size will be 3.25 GB.

After the download is complete you can copy C:\vs2017usb folder to a USB drive for later install.  However, when you run the setup.exe you still need to connect to the internet so the installer can verify the certificates. After the certificates are downloaded you can disconnect the internet and continue setup.exe install)

Comment: not completely answered... because while it does download VS... its not an offline installer because it requires an internet connection and updates the packages even if they are fully downloaded...  does help if your internet connection is not good however... just curious if anybody knows how to fix that so its a fully offline installer...